# Как отобразить фото из базы данных?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть поля в базе. Текстовые считываю и работаю. А как быть, если есть поле типа image и надо отобразить его в объекте image?

Answer (score 1):

Просто рассматриваете изображение как массив байтов и грузите его из базу или в базы.

```
Image image;

string sql = "SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = @ID";
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

sc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

connection.Open();

try {
    image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[])sc.ExecuteScalar()));
}
catch {
}
finally {
    connection.Close();
}
```

Или наоборот

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
}
```

И т.д.

P.S. Код не проверял.